How to extrude so text comes out smoothly

When I am trying to extrude, the text RIP is coming out along with the backstone behind. I want the backstone to stay there and the text to come out smoothly

maybe right click > Shade Smooth in Object mode and give a modifier > Normals > Smooth by Angle? or please share your file

Hello and welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the post. It should read like a question, be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the problem so that anyone searching for similar issues is likely to find this. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "this", "help with", "issue" or "question about", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on it. See What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"

That looks a lot like a shading artifact more than the backstone being deformed. Try W->Shade Flat to see if that helps. Otherwise, you could just separate the letter to be their own separate object. You won't get good lighting usually if you are using that many ngons

It looks like bad shading, in Object mode, either:

RMB > Shade Flat
Or, if you want smooth shading, RMB > Shade Smooth and give a modifier > Normals > Smooth by Angle

